# Canonical inclusion $L^q(0,1) \to L^p(0,1)$ is compact?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, compact-operators

Does there exist $q>p$ such that the canonical inclusion $L^q(0,1) \to L^p(0,1)$ is compact?

My answer is no.

Since we know that $L^\infty (0,1) \to L^p(0,1)$ is not compact, take $\{\sin(nx)\}$ as a counter example; this counter example will also work for $L^q$.

Is my argument correct? And what if I change "compact" to "weakly compact"? Because then my counter example would fail.

Another question, is there any connection between the weak topology on $L^p$ and the strong topology on $L^q$? My guess is no, since the weak topology is not metrizable.

Comment: Banach Alaouglu says that the unit ball of a dual space is compact in the weak-* topology, but since each of the $L^p$ are dual spaces themselves, you can really just think of this as the weak topology. There are some details to check, which I cannot do since I'm just rushing out the door, but at a glance I think that should do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $1\le p<q<\infty$, then the embedding 
$$L^q(0, 1)\subset L^p(0, 1)$$
trivially is weakly compact. Indeed, an $L^q$-bounded sequence is $L^p$-bounded too, and by Banach-Alaoglu's theorem (which applies since $q\ne 1, \infty$) it has weakly convergent subsequences.